# Python output formatting issues

Tags: python, numpy, format, output

Not sure about the syntax of the output I am receving. Any help would be appreciated. 
Here is my code:

```
import numpy

def g(): #generate random complex values
    return numpy.random.random(1) + numpy.random.random(1) *1j

p = numpy.poly1d(numpy.squeeze([g(),g(),g()]))  # test function p
pprime = numpy.polyder(p) #derivative of p

print 'Our p(x) is {} '. format(p)
print('\n') # new line
print'Our pprime(x) is {} '. format(pprime)  #apply newtons method to p
print('\n') # new line

#apply newtons method to p
def root_newton ( f, df, tolerance = 1.0e-6):
    dx = 2 * tolerance
    x=0
    while dx > tolerance:
        x1 = x - f(x)/df(x)
        dx = abs (x - x1)
        x = x1
    return x
print('Our first root is at {}'.format(root_newton(p,pprime)))
print('\n') # new line
```

Here's the output:

```
Our p(x) is                    2
(0.6957 + 0.683j) x + (0.3198 + 0.5655j) x + (0.9578 + 0.1899j) 


Our pprime(x) is  
(1.391 + 1.366j) x + (0.3198 + 0.5655j) 


Our first root is at (0.00925817978737+0.830966156841j)


The correct roots are [-0.64968928-1.01513333j  0.00925818+0.83096616j]
```

What does the 2 above the second component in my first line outputted mean? I can't find anything similar to my question online. I am guessing it may mean the x component is squared but I'm not sure? This is python 3 by the way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `2` is the exponent on the first `x`, misaligned because you put text before it on the same line.

If we take your output:

```
Our p(x) is                    2
(0.6957 + 0.683j) x + (0.3198 + 0.5655j) x + (0.9578 + 0.1899j)
```

and remove the text you prepended:

```
                   2
(0.6957 + 0.683j) x + (0.3198 + 0.5655j) x + (0.9578 + 0.1899j)
```

the intended meaning of the `2` becomes clearer.